# How to use vector default constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I recently learned how to use the vecor library in C++. I don't understant what is the vector default constructor or when should I use it.

If for example I have a struct and want to create a vector of n structs. Is the following code valid:

```
 struct item
{
    string id;
    string name;
};

    vector <item> vitem;

    vitem.push_back(item());
```

Does this vector have one element? or no elements at all?

Comment: `std::cout << vitem.size() << std::endl` holds the answer to your question.

Comment: After the default constructor the vector contains zero elements, and after pushing one element into the vector you have one element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this calls the default constructor. A default constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments. The default constructor of `std::vector` initializes the vector with zero elements.

```
std::vector<item> items; // implicitly calls default constructor
```

Comment: Okay. Is it always necessary to call it? like when constructing a class?

Comment: You don’t have to call it explicitly. The compiler inserts the call for you.

Comment: One last question. If I want to add more elements to the vector using the push_back function should I use the constructor again?

Comment: @Reboot_87 No. Once the vector is constructed you can add elements without constructing it again.

Answer (score 0):

It has.
The ctor is called immediately if you are declaring vector as var instead pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> If for example I have a struct and want to create a vector of n
>   structs. Is the following code valid:

No, this code is invalid because it does not create a vector of n structures. It creates an empty vector. If you want to create a vector of n structures you should explicitly specify the number of created elements. For example

```
std::vector<item> vitem( n );
```

or you can at first create an empty vector and then resize it. For example

```
srd::vector<item> vitem;
vitem.resize( n );
```

Or you can use method assign

```
std::vector<item> vitem;
vitem.assign( n, item() );
```